# Bootstrap3 Typeahead - Empty message

Tags: typeahead

I didn't understand how to make it appear the "empty" message in bootstrap3 typeahead. I am using the custom template but what value must be assigned to source to make it appear?
Here is my code (not working):

```
<script>

function doSomething() {
 var states = [];
 $("#test").typeahead({     
    source : states,
    minLength: 3,
    templates: { 
        empty: ['<div>',
            'No Items Found',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n')
           }
    });
}
</script>
[...]
<body onLoad="doSomething();">
   <input class="typeahead" type="text" id="test">
</body>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I confused typeahead (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) with bootstrap3 typeahead (https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead).

The question is wrong because the code above is correct for https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js, instead I had included https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead, which is a different library and have different options.

Comment: This is not an answer. You have to explain your question to explain this.